# Exist the easiest way to call outer class method from inner class

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
class Window(QtWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_gui()

    def init_gui(self):
        layout = GRidLayout(self)

        icon = QIcon("icon.png")        
        button = self.Button(0, self)
        button.set_icon(icon)
        button.set_menu()
        button.init()
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.show()

    def gui_button_method(self):
        print("LOL")

    class Button(QToolButton):
        def __init__(self, style, window_self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setToolButtonStyle(style)
            self.window_self = window_self
            self.action = QAction()

        def set_icon(self, icon):
            self.action.setIcon(icon)

        def set_menu(self):
            menu = QMenu()
            menu.addAction("BUTTON METHOD", self.window_self.gui_button_method)
            self.setMenu(menu)
            self.setPopupMode(2)

        def init(self):
            self.setDefaultAction(self.action)
```

I call the class Window method gui_button_method sending self of Window parameter to class Button.

Is there easiest way to do it?

I read a lot of solutions on this website, but none is good as my solution. But my solution seems to me like a bad code, or am I wrong?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any reason for `Button` to be an inner class. You just need an instance of `Window` (apparently) when you create an instance of `Button`: `w = Window(); b = Button(some_style, w)`.